# stackdriver in node.js : The caller does not have permission

Tags: node.js, logging, google-api, stackdriver

I'm struggling in using the stackdriver logging api (`googleapi.logging.entries.write`) to log errors and information in the GCP project.
I'm using a service account (used also for more than 20 APIs without issue).

The scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.admin has been set to the service account, as well as the role "logging admin" in the GCP IAM console.

MoreOver, I have added a superadmin user in the impersonate mode ("subject" in the JWT options)

However, I still have the error "The caller does not have permission" while calling the logging API, although the oAuthClient has been well set.

What additional role or scope or permission to add to make this running ?

Please note that there is a lack of example and documentation to use the logging api, which makes things confusing, especially where to set the auth, since it appears in 2 different places. It should be set in the logging({}) options, and/or in the entries.write({}) options ? I tried all combinations, all of them failed with the same authorization error.

Thanks for your help

```js
    import { google } from "googleapis";
    const t = await google.logging({ version: "v2", auth }).entries.write({
            auth,
            requestBody: {
                logName: "projects/THEPROJECT/logs/THELOGS",
                resource: {
                    type: "project",
                    labels: {
                        projectId: "THEPROJECT",
                    },
                },
                entries: [
                    {
                        severity: "INFO",
                        jsonPayload: {
                            source: "code",
                            value: "test",
                            details: "this is INFO log test",
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        });
        console.log(t.status);
```

Comment: I have always used the following package ... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging/latest/index.html  which is @google-cloud/logging.  I'm now confused as to the apparent existence of two libraries "npm googleapis" and "npm @google-cloud/logging".

Comment: I also had a look at this package, but where to set the authentification (the google token) ? Do you have an example ? I don't want to use an environment variable. thks

Comment: If we look at the Logging constructor ... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging/latest/Logging.html  we see it takes an options object ... https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/logging/latest/global.html#ClientConfig

In that options object you can provide the name/userid/email of the identity to present to GCP and a file name that contains the key.  (email and keyFilename fields).  These provide the authentication information that we need.

Comment: using the API mentionned by Kolban fixed the problem. I guess the other API is not correct. Thks